# Return the first letter

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to return first letter of first name and last name.
I already know the `substring` and the `left` but if it has 2 names with different number of characters, it gives me wrong values.

Comment: Single column with delimited values?

Comment: some sample data will be appreciated

Comment: Could you please tell the scenario if it has 2 names with different characters?

Comment: Which SQL Server version would help too. Could you have someone with 3 names, what about double barrelled? I.e. George Walker Bush and David Lloyd-George.

Comment: `CHARINDEX` to find the space between names, then `SUBSTRING` of first and N+1 chars. Concatenated with `+`.

Comment: Add Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Jonathan Rhys-Davies and Carl van der Walt to the sample data!

Comment: SQL Server 2016 added STRING_SPLIT. There are other functions to split strings in earlier versions. Which version are you using?

Comment: Aaron Bertrand has written many articles comparing the performance of various string splitting techniques. Obviously the fastest is STRING_SPLIT. Other techniques are explained [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) with the fastest being a SQLCLR implementation and a close contender that uses XML

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
declare @a varchar(20)

set @a = 'John Smith'

select LEFT(@a,1) + substring(@a, charindex(' ', @a)+1 , 1)
```